# Virtualenv and Django apps not playing well together

Tags: django, virtualenv

I have decided that it was time to move to virtualenv for my django projects.  All is working well except one thing.  Even though the apps installed with pip into my virtualenv can be imported into my project without issue, any .urls, templates, template tags, etc. in those apps are not found when running the dev server.

I checked my python path in the environment and the site-packages directory with my installs are in the path.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

--- added information ---

Since I am still having issues, I am adding more information to this ticket.  I am sure it is something I am doing, just can't figure out what it is. Starting with a fresh environment, tested on both ubuntu and osx.

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages testpjt
```

Then I use pip to add just django and django smuggler.  Here is the requirements text

```
-e svn+http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk#egg=Django
django-smuggler==0.1.1-final
```

Then I install requirements with pip

```
pip install -E testpjt -r requirements.txt
```

Every thing seems to install fine.  So I start the virtual environment and make the following changes to files:

```
source ../bin/activate
```

Add smuggler to installed apps:

```
    INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'smuggler',
)
```

Add admin and smuggler to the urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        (r'^admin/', include('smuggler.urls')),
        (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    )
```

I then sync the db and start the server:

```
../bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I can go to ip/admin and I get the admin interface..  I go to ip/admin/load (dump, any of the smuggler urls) and I get a 404.

For testing I can enter the django shell and:

```
from smuggler import urls
```

and get no errors, so I know they are there.

If I put a copy of smuggler in the base of my project directory it works just fine.

Comment: Have you put all those apps to INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: Yes, they are in INSTALLED_APPS and I don't get any errors from the settings file.  In-fact if I run from the django shell I can "import appname" with no issue.  If I try "from appname.forms import formname" it tells me it can not be found.

Comment: Can you show the contents of your INSTALLED_APPS and the output of pip freeze?

Comment: Sorry @rz, I missed your comment.  I have added the information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You are activating the virtual environment before running the dev server right?

Comment: Yes, I am activating the virtual environment first.

Comment: Since you are not getting any errors running the dev server, it might be possible that there is something wrong with the virtual environment itself. Have you tried creating another one for testing purposes?

Comment: Yes, and have tried it on both OSX and Ubuntu systems.  Really confused as to what is going on.

Comment: What is the command line that you use to create the virtual environments?

Comment: virtualenv ENVNAME --no-site-packages

Comment: Does the system python install work correctly?
From within your ve does the following work correctly?
from django.conf import settings

Comment: Yes. if I run python once inside my environment and "from django.conf import settings" It imports with no errors.

Comment: I actually have no issues with any django built in functionality.  It is only with other apps.  Example - I am trying to add the django-smuggler application.  It can be imported just fine..  but when I add "(r'^admin/', include('smuggler.urls'))," per the install instructions I get a 404 because it can not find smuggler.urls, even though it found smuggler just fine.

Comment: I started a new virtualenv, and a new django project and only added django-smuggler.  Same issue.  Smuggler can be imported but smuggler.urls can not be found.

Comment: Can you post your urls.py and the INSTALLED_APPS section of your settings. Also what version of python and Django are you using? I just did an install with python 2.6.6 and Django 1.2.3 on Debian and it worked just fine.

Comment: @bmeyer71 thanks so much on your help on this.  I have more information to the question above

Comment: Try going to /admin/import or /admin/export. I took a look at the urls for smuggler and there is no load url. The version I installed from pypi didn't have a load or dump option.

Comment: sorry, they changed those and I was a little on auto-pilot when I wrote above :).  /admin/import  /admin/export also give 404s

Comment: With your ve activated, can you get your python path and paste it here?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here might be that you are installing django-smuggler outside the virtual-env.

First activate the virtual-env.
Then install django-smuggler in virtual-env and it should work fine.